# Licensing a spring boot application inside an AMI

Tags: java, licensing

Say we have a standalone spring boot application which we are going to distribute by creating an AMI and sharing on the AWS marketplace. Since the jar is available inside the AMI, **I want to stop a user from buying the AMI on the marketplace and then redistributing my jar file**.

This is my current implementation plan for this:

1. When building the jar, I bundle a blank file (ex: test.abc) with the jar
2. When user starts jar for the first time, I check if this file is blank, if it is, then I write the mac address of the current machine into the file
3. Validate the file to check if the mac address on the file is same as the mac address of the machine

There will also need to be a way of "hiding" the file test.abc from the user so he/she cannot rebundle the jar with another blank test.abc.

Is there a better/industrial standard of meeting this requirement?

Comment: I don't think your question format is correct. This seems more like a: *How do I prevent people from illegally distributing my application?* The answer is, you can't. Once you give the source code (in any form - assembly, jar,...) to an end user, with enough motivation they can reverse engineer the application and crack it. Your only solution is to offer your application as a service, whose source end users cannot touch, and therefore you can implement any protection mechanism you find reliable enough.

Comment: This is typically accomplished using a license that you provide to the customer which is then validated by the software, either using a call to your license server or using an algorithm in the software.